# how to pass id on button in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have created project scaffold.
project scaffold has one_to_many association with financials. now i want to render financial's index in project#show but i not able to pass project_id on creation of financial#new. here is my code-

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @financials = current_user.projects.includes(:financials).find(params[:id])
```

project#show.html.erb

```
<%= render "financials/index" %>
```

financial#_index.html.erb (here i am getting error on this button rest working)

```
<%= link_to ' Add New Financial', new_project_financial_path, :class=>"button primary fi-plus" %>
```

Comment: What does your error say?

Comment: error-```No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"financials", :id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:project_id]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to ' Add New Financial', new_project_financial_path(@project.id), :class=>"button primary fi-plus" %>
```